# SQS Message size

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

From my understanding of the docs, the queue entry size is limited to 256KB. Is the SQS even supposed to hold "objects" that need to passed on to readers of the queue? 
What alternate solutions are available in case I need to pass objects that are >256KB in size (split them, maybe?)

Comment: Upper limit is also there..
Maximum request size of request can't exceed: 1 MB. If it exceeds it returns: HTTP Status 413.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In such cases you would store most of the object outside of the message, in S3 or another database and store a pointer to that object within your SQS message.

Comment: I figured this out after doing a lot more reading. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi Lelouch.. Thanks for the answer. can you provide some useful docs/refrences to support the same..
Thanks